# Dropping H2 in memory DB between integeration tests in maven

Tags: spring, maven, h2

I have the following scenario.
I have an Hibernate-Spring Project, which works on mySQL on production, and uses H2 in-memory DB for integration tests, which is created on-the-fly.
Currently, when I run the integeration tests with maven, I get errors, because the database is maintained between the tests. this is unacceptable, because I planned my tests to run on a fresh DB.
How do I force the deletion of all data in the DB between the tests ?
Is there a way to tell maven to drop the schema and generate it again for each test file ?

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at [Spring's support for embedded databases](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-support).  You can let Spring do the database creation and setup for you and provide you access to it as a simple `DataSource`.  All you really need to do is provide the sql scripts to create/populate the database, and with each run, the database will be re-created.

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="h2">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Don't forget the `jdbc` namespace:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you running the integration tests? Spring has a built-in support for [transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx) tests. Also you can manually DROP and recreate the database after each test, this is pretty simple:

```
SCRIPT NOPASSWORDS DROP TO 'file.sql'
```

And then restore it with:

```
RUNSCRIPT FROM 'file.sql'
```

I guess virtually every testing framework [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/)/[TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.htm)/[Fitensse](http://fitnesse.org/)/[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)/... allows to run some custom code before all tests and after each and every.

[Here](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/11/spring-pitfalls-transactional-tests.html) is my blog post explaining how it works and an example setup for [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org).

Comment: You're right, actually I'm using JUnit 4 with Spring context. and I'm filling referential data in the database before the test begin. The problem is that this reference data is causing an error because the insert statements of the other tests cause unique constraint error. I can't do a "insert if not exists" because there isn't a standard for this in SQL, and the syntax is different for mySQL and H2. so I only left with the option of dropping the entire schema.